# Translate IsPrivate check into Enhanced Notes

Tags: contentversion, contentdocumentlink, contentnote

I am migrating notes into Enhanced Notes, How do I move the IsPrivate(Checkbox on Notes) values into Enhanced Notes?
If the IsPrivate Checkbox is checked on Notes, how can I do this on EnhancedNotes?

Comment: Based on the document https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm, you need to set the SharingPrivacy picklist field

Comment: Thanks for that information, I am trying to understanding what are the picklist values on SharingPrivacy field on ContentNote object. Can you help here.

Comment: Its mentioned in the above link